# Plausibility of detecting viruses using optical spectra

Tags: spectroscopy, biophysics, experimental-technique, nanoscience, imaging

Ok, this is a huge long shot, and I also apologise if this is a poor question (I'm a newbie here...). This doesn't seem to me a strictly perfect fit for Chemistry.SE, Biology.SE, or Photography.SE either, so hopefully it's acceptable here, given that there is some level of Physics involved...(please move if necessary) Here goes...!

Research relating to taking optical spectral signatures of viruses seems somewhat hard to come by on the web (quite understandably so given their characteristics), but I am nonetheless curious as to whether the following (admittedly utterly crazy) apparatus might be at all theoretically plausible, or just an impossible fantasy:

Could it be possible, by fitting a spectrograph of sufficient resolution to a relatively low-cost optical camera (such that of a cellphone) under the following conditions:

- Adequate lighting conditions.
- Capturing large numbers of 'raw', uncompressed, unprocessed frames.
- Applying stacking techniques similar to those used in Astronomy to
  increase effective exposure time and improve SNR when imageing very
  faint objects.
- Performing the aforementioned stacking operation and saving the
  result at extremely High Dynamic Range (due to the faintness of the
  target signal relative to the noise and also the total amount of
  light being collected).

Be able to detect some kind of super-faint characteristic spectral signature from the proteins or other molecules of, say, a virus (such as SARS-CoV-2) on a surface/clinical sample.

Given that these techniques work on extremely faint stars, galaxies, and other celestial objects, it seems the plausibility of this would depend heavily on how much of a (feeble) unique spectral signature (if any) molecules in a virus present on a surface might impart on light reflecting off that surface.

Alternatively might some kind of incredibly faint uniquely characteristic diffraction pattern caused by the virus particles be detectable using a similar method?

Thanks!

Comment: What about engineering se?

Comment: @Aaron Would this perhaps be more on-topic as an Engineering.SE question? It looked to me as though Engineering.SE had more of a focus on Mechanical engineering, though I'm still familiarising myself with things here...

Comment: @AaronStevens I think that trying to capture a spectrum is more [tag:experimental-technique] than engineering.

Comment: Yeah, the problem with questions like these is that they cross many disciplines. I am basing this off of our close banner for engineering questions that says *This question appears to be about engineering, which is the application of scientific knowledge to construct a solution to solve a specific problem. As such, it is off topic for this site, which deals with the science, whether theoretical or experimental, of how the natural world works.*

Comment: @rob I guess I am just basing my opinion off of the close reason above. This question seems to be asking more about application rather than understanding any specific physics concepts

Comment: @AaronStevens I feel like there are lots of questions about [tag:experimental-technique] that fit better in Physics than in Engineering, but to which that wording applies. I'd like to change that. Changing that in general is a discussion for [meta] which I don't really have the energy for; however I'm pretty sure migration to [engineering.se] is not a path that will get more answers for this particular question.

Comment: Maybe UV spectroscopy? http://www.microspectra.com/support/learn/protein-absorption But I have no idea how useful it is for detecting specific viruses on a surface.

Comment: Hopeless. A virus particle is too small to be seen with an optical microscope. // UV-Vis has broad bands and is relatively non-specific.  Techniques like NMR and IR are only useful for relatively pure samples. You'd only get a significant diffraction pattern from larger crystals, not individual virus particles.,

Comment: @MaxW That seems like an answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: @MaxW I'm not so much thinking if the virus can be imaged here (which I know is impossible at optical wavelengths), but more about detecting faint spectral features caused by them interacting in some tiny way with the light falling on them.

Answer (score 0):

I see two major problems with your approach: signal to noise ratio and specificity.

Astronomy uses light sources on a dark background. The fact that the sources are faint and require all the techniques you mentioned is not that bad due to the dark background, but try to acquire the image of a star in broad daylight...The same goes with your virus. The number of viruses is relatively small, whatever technique you use. If you have other signals at the same wavelength, the signal will disappear.

This brings me to what I think is your best shot: fluorescence. For example, see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15339207 which mentions that viruses contain molecules (mainly tryptophan in proteins) that can exhibit fluorescence. If you can control illumination (dark room with your own source at specific wavelength), you can filter the source wavelength and image the specific wavelengths created by fluorescence, you may be able to detect fluorescence created by viruses. Stacking images may even allow you to image distribution on a surface.

The problem will probably be specificity. You will detect in this manner a lot of tryptophan containing object on your surface. Many viruses and proteins will be visible. I doubt you can get specific enough to detect a specific virus. This is why tests that use fluorescence tag viruses with a specific (fluorescent) molecule and then image the molecule, you then get the specificity you needed, but I may be wrong. If you can combine many fluorescence signals from the same item to obtain a signature, your detection scheme could just maybe be possible, but any device to do so would probably be very complex and expensive.

Comment: So the paper abstract does mention that trp has different fluorescent properties depending on where it is found, which makes sense. So your statement of *You will detect in this manner any tryptophan containing object on your surface* might not be entirely true.

Comment: I still expect a lot problems with getting to the virus species level, but this was maybe an exaggeration. I corrected the answer. If you look at the original paper, you will see that the observed spectrum does not consist of spectral lines, but of a diffuse peak. They can distinguish between a bacteriophage and its host cell in vivo. This is impressive. However, this a big step from reaching specifically identifying a specific virus from all existing viruses.

Comment: Even presuming you can get a signature for each virus, in the wild, your observed signal would be the sum of all signals from all viruses in your field of view. So, maybe you can say "yes there is a virus" or "no, there is no virus", and I am not sure you can get the right signal to noise ratio to do so, but identifying a specific virus species, I really think that will be impossible unless you can get other observations (not just trp shift). You can still try if you want. That would make a good start for a cool PhD project, if scaled appropriately during the process.

Comment: Thanks @ManuelFortin for your answer. A very interesting read there about the fluorescence approach! I guess the trick would be finding a tag molecule that sticks to the virus you're after..

Re. SNR and background, might one have more luck if you could capture 'Background frames' of a known clean 'identical' object placed close to the target, or otherwise take an 'average' across all frames captured in the stack, and subtract this from the final stacked result to hopefully yield a clearer signal? Could any optical signal be detectable from a virus even in 'theoretically ideal' conditions?

Comment: @warpcore. Tagging with fluorescent markers is used extensively in biology. This is what antibody based tests do. Regarding your other questions,viruses are smaller then visible wavelengths, so passive reflection is not possible.. Any single virus will also only emit a tiny bit of light. If you have more questions, maybe posting them as proper questions with the details of what you understand or not would improve your chances of understanding the physics involved as everybody on the site could contribute.

Comment: specificity is usually addressed in biology-biophysics by 1) antibodies linked to a fluorescence molecule (a protein like GFP or a smaller organic dye). the antibody recognize its target and labels it fluorescently. 2) my genetic mutations, where possible. the gene of the target protein is fused to the one of, say, GFP so the result is the protein of interest hard-linked to the fluorophore. Today detecting on a camera single fluorophores is routinely done.